# DRF permission issue even after sending a valid token for a get request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, postman

serializer.py

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """for all  getting all objects of a particular user """
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    author=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','title','rate','author','content','review','url','tags')
```

views.py

```
class PostListUser(generics.ListAPIView, APIView):
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes =(TokenAuthentication,JSONWebTokenAuthentication)

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Post.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

urls.py

url('^me/$', PostListUser.as_view()),

but when i tried to hit a get request with all the Authorization headers I have got this response

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

[image: here is the image of get request in postman]

Comment: Is your AUTH_HEADER_TYPES setting correct? https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html
maybe try with Bearer instead of JWT?

Comment: even after using  bearer this is the response {
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Comment: 'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',  is this what you are talking about

Comment: or should i change     'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',), in JWT of my setttings ?

Comment: still the same even after changing  'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),

Comment: My bad, please edit the question to specify which package you're using, I think it's this one? https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage because there's another one linked in the DRF docs. Check the configuration or maybe set AllowAny as permission class (just for debugging!) since it could as well be a permissions issue https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: even after changing permission to allowany still im gettign the same error